# jQuery animation over div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to expand the `div` element to the left side, or expand over div. Now it expands to the right side. I'm also trying to close the button after click. I've just started hard courses, so it's very hard to keep on track.
this is broken.
[image: broken]
this is what i need.
[image: fixed]

https://jsfiddle.net/GreyFox/01sbv4y2/3/

```js
$(function() {
  var $button = $('.btn2');
  $button.on('click', function(e) {
    $(".sidebar2").animate({
      marginleft: "400px",
      opacity: '0.5',
      height: '150px',
      width: '450px',
      margin: '0'
    });

    if ($(this).html() == 'Close') {
      $(this).html('GET MORE INFO');
    } else {
      $(this).html('Close');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar-wrap {}

.sidebar2 {
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  min-height: 308px;
  background-color: #2355ce;
}

.hiddenp {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidewrap" 
  <div class="sidebar2">
    <h2>MOBILE DEVELOPMENT</h2>
    <p>Have business in your pocket!</p>
    <br>
    <a class="btn2" href="#">details</a>
    <p class="hiddenp">selector is used to select the selector is used to select the</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited your question to include all the code from the jsFiddle. I also removed your request for help using the site as it's off-topic for the question you've asked. If you want to understand how this site works and the types of questions you should ask, try taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [reading the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/01sbv4y2/29/

Comment: now its shrinking to the right side,i want it to expand to left side. i need to animate the block over the div to the left. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: uploaded a photo to be more exact.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/01sbv4y2/45/

It expands to the left as you have requested.

```
$(function() {
var $button = $('.btn2');
$button.on('click', function(e) {
    $(".sidebar2").animate({        marginRight: "400px",
    opacity: '0.5',
    height: '150px',
    width: '450px',
    margin: '0'
});

    if ($(this).html() == 'Close') {
        $(this).html('GET MORE INFO');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Close');
    }
});

});
```

Comment: same result as in first photo. browser expands to right and breaks the web.